# Javascript function parameter to be used as constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a reusable module, with lesser code. Will something like this work? (Well, not really going to work, it's just an example to give you the idea)

```
var test = function(foo) {
    var bar = new foo(); // The keyword foo is from the parameter
}
```

The parameter is actually a string. So if I passed "FooBar", a `FooBar` object will be created.

It's like saying:

```
var test = function('FooBar') {
    var bar = new 'FooBar'(); 
}
```

Are there other elegant ways which would fit the solution I'm looking for?

Many thanks!

Comment: That should work just fine, so long as `foo` is a function. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: Can you please tell or explain more about what exactly you want.

Comment: Edited. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is a constructor function, then your code will work just fine (I'm curious why you didn't just try it).  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yT6Vk/.

If you want advise on other/better ways to solve your problem, you'll have to back up and describe more about what you're really trying to do.

There are alternate ways of doing things like this such as factory functions or a single function that examines it's arguments to decide which type of object to create, but without more info on exactly what problem you're trying to solve, we can't really say whether other methods are better/worse than what you already have.

A disadvantage of this method is that you haven't allowed for any arguments to be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Douglas Crockford's method

```
var booze = {
    beer:'ale',
    wine: 'pinot noir'
}

//test(X)

var createObject = function(o){
    function F () {}
    F.prototype = o
    return new F()
}

var test = function () {
    var x = createObject(booze)
    return x;
}

test()
```